# Is there a way to use typescript to have conditional props in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

In Vue script setup with TS, I want to define props as follows :

- Title is mandatory
- if either isRepeatableParent or isRepeatableChild is set to true (they're boolean and can be ommited), repeatableControls is mandatory
- if isRepeatableChild is set to true, subtitle is mandatory

I have this code :

```
type BaseProps = {
    title: string;
};

type RepeatableParentProps = BaseProps & {
    isRepeatableParent: true;
    repeatableControls: IRepeatableControls<IRepeatableBlock>;
    isRepeatableChild?: never;
    subtitle?: never;
};

type RepeatableChildProps = BaseProps & {
    isRepeatableChild: true;
    repeatableControls: IRepeatableControls<IRepeatableBlock>;
    subtitle: string;
    isRepeatableParent?: never;
};

type OtherProps = BaseProps & {
    isRepeatableParent?: false;
    isRepeatableChild?: false;
    repeatableControls?: never;
    subtitle?: never;
};

type Props = RepeatableParentProps | RepeatableChildProps | OtherProps;

const props = defineProps<Props>();
```

When I set is-repeatable-parent on the component, I don't get any errors if I try to add subtitle.
Also, sometimes, all the props other than title dissapear from the suggestions...
I'm using PHPStorm as an IDE so this might affect the outcome.

I also tried to use a type prop (instead of isRepeatableParent and isRepeatableChild) to try to help TS narrow down the type but it didn't seem to help.

Am I doing this wrong? Have I misunderstood the capabilities of typescript here ? Is there a way to do what I'm trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

use the following type and see if it fits your requirement

```
type Props = { title: string } & (
  | {
      isRepeatableParent: true;
      isRepeatableChild?: false;
      repeatableControls: IRepeatableControls<IRepeatableBlock>;;
      subtitle?:never
    }
  | {
      isRepeatableParent?: false;
      isRepeatableChild: true;
      repeatableControls: IRepeatableControls<IRepeatableBlock>;;
      subtitle: string;
    }
  | {
      isRepeatableParent: true;
      isRepeatableChild: true;
      repeatableControls: IRepeatableControls<IRepeatableBlock>;;
      subtitle: string;
    }
  | {
      isRepeatableParent?: false;
      isRepeatableChild?: false;
      repeatableControls?:never;
      subtitle?:never
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I just tried this and it works but only in the script section, it doesn't work in the template section, and vue still doesn't suggest 'subtitle' when I specify isRepeatableChild. I don't think it's a typescript problem but a Volar or Typescript Language Server problem...